# How to route vnc traffic over ssh tunnel?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, vnc, mobaxterm, vncserver

I am trying to route the `vnc` traffic via `ssh` reverse tunnel from my raspberry pi to a remote server (`Ubuntu`). The setup is:

1. Using the default realvnc server as part of `Raspbian` (`Bullseye`) image. realvnc server is running; tested with `systemctl status vncserver-x11-serviced.service`. SSH is also enabled on Pi.
2. In the RealVNC application, VNC password is set and also standard user is selected.
3. Now I am opening a reverse `ssh` tunnel from Pi to a remote server in different network and port forwarding the `vnc port` (5901). The command looks like

```
ssh -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -R 61000:localhost:5901 rpi3@my-server.com sleep 300
```

Tunnel is kept open using `sleep 300`.
4. Now when I try to establish a vnc session using `mobaxterm` software (it has built-in support for vnc) I am getting below error

```
No configured security type is supported by 3.3 VNC Viewer
Failed to connect to server
```

I can check in the remote server that forwarded port is connected and in LISTEN state. `sudo lsof -i -n | grep ssh | grep IPv4 | grep LISTEN`

Also checked that there are no firewall rules blocking the port or connection. And local connection (without ssh) is working fine.

Also tried with RealVNC Viewer and same issue.

Can anyone please let me know what could be the issue  here and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing